# Have any one-hit wonders later returned to become multi-hit successes?

Tags: chart-success

Obviously every multi-hit success story starts with a single hit, and if they have another hit they're not a one-hit wonder. But are there any examples of a musician or band having one big hit, disappearing into the comparative oblivion of one-hit wonders lists, and later returning to further success?

I could make the terms of the question more specific, but that might eliminate a notable example that *almost* fits the spirit of the question. But I'll offer some specifics as a starting point.

By "one-hit wonder", I mean a musician or band that gets a top 40 single, no other singles that chart at all, and no albums that chart unless they include the top 40 single.

By a long disappearance, I mean they don't get anything else on a hits chart for at least ten years.

And by returning to further success, I mean any song or album on a top 40 list.

In case no one fits that exact list of definitions, are there examples that almost fit? Maybe they original hit only made it to #42. Maybe they were only gone from the charts for nine years. Maybe they has a bunch of top-10 songs, but none made it to the top 40. (But if some examples fit the specific definition, let's stick to them, to preserve the question nature of this question, and not turn it into a discussion that goes against Stack Exchange format.)

Comment: Most definitions of "hit" usually mean that the song reached the top 40 of a national chart, such as the Billboard Magazine Hot 100 (in the US). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hit_wonder

Comment: I will revise to follow that definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**General Public** with:

- [*Tenderness*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XegL32Btzs) in 1984: [#51 in Hot 100](https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/1984-12-29).
- [*I'll Take You There*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0N_Q0JqH80) in 1994: [#22 in Hot 100](https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/1994-05-28).

---

Honrable Mention (less than 10 years) for **Michael Jachson** with:

- [*Ben*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwKWiZAuHoQ) in 1972: #20 in Hot 100.
- [*Don't Stop 'Til You Get Enough*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yURRmWtbTbo) in 1979: #1 in Hot 100.